# Canvas drawImage does not draw in Cordova, security issue?

Tags: javascript, cordova, canvas, drawimage, code-access-security

I want to draw an image to canvas within a Cordova app.

When the image path is within the `www` directory of my app, the drawing works as expected.
However, if the image is made by the Cordova camera and is thus stored in `../../tmp` in relation to the `www` directory, the `drawImage(...)` produces a black picture.

This might be a security issue, since the app's source code is found in the `www` directory, but the images are not. On the other hand, an `<img>` tag can show these images without a problem.

Is the problem really a security issue? And what can I do to solve it, i.e. to not produce a black picture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying out an endless amount of things:
The problem was simply that the image which I wanted to use with `drawImage()` was too high res. Lowering the resolution made the problem disappear: the canvas is not black anymore... (so not a security issue)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to access the image directly through the file system. You will want to use the Cordova API for retrieving the images

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture

See the full example for retrieving

```
var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 

// Wait for Cordova to connect with the device
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

// Cordova is ready to be used!
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
  // Uncomment to view the base64 encoded image data
  // console.log(imageData);

  // Get image handle
  //
  var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
  smallImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
  // Uncomment to view the image file URI 
  // console.log(imageURI);

  // Get image handle
  //
  var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
  largeImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  largeImage.src = imageURI;
}


// A button will call this function
//
function getPhoto(source) {
  // Retrieve image file location from specified source
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: source });
}

// Called if something bad happens.
// 
function onFail(message) {
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

HTML

```
<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br>
<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button><br>
<img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
<img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
```